# ajax call not working when it is called inside javascript

Tags: php, ajax

here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function update(value)
{
var ack=value.ack;
var phone=value.phone;
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {

  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 )
    {

    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }

  }
  //alert("validate_offline_payment.php?ack="+ack);
//xmlhttp.open("GET","validate_offline_payment.php?ack="+ack,true);
 xmlhttp.open("get","validate_offline_payment.php?ack="+ack,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}


</script>
```

i have create a file validate_offline_payment
and just printing

```
echo $_GET['ack'];
```

but it is not working
can any1 plz help me wat is the bug m facing

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console log ?

Comment: You can try to debug your code on the client side (Developper tools for Chrome for instance) and see what is post. Maybe some console.debug with the initial input value can also help

Answer (score 0):

Please use jQuery ajax or something like that

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
function addToBookmark(var){
    var postUrl = siteUrl + 'url/test';
    $.post(postUrl, 
        {guuid : guuid}, 
        function(response) {
            if(response.stat=='success'){
                alert('ok');
            } else {
                alert('err');
            }
        },
        'json'
    );
}
```